# Clash with `english` option in custom class and `babel`

Tags: babel, class-options

I am writing a class file which takes an option `english` and then loads the `article` class. The `english` option defined in the new class *is **not** passed to* `article`.
However, if then I load `babel` with option `USenglish`, then I get the warning

```
Package Babel Warning: The package option `english' should not be used
(Babel)                with a more specific one (like `USenglish')
```

as if `english` was passed to the `article` class.

Here is how I pass the options to my class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2020/11/07 myclass template]

\newif\ifEnglish\Englishfalse

\DeclareOption{english}{\Englishtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\ClassWarning{myclass}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
```

The code

```
\documentclass[english]{myclass}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
```

produces the `babel` warning above.
**How can I fix this?**

I understand that a warning is not an error, but (1) I want to make sure that the scope of the `english` option I define is limited to `myclass` and is not inherited by `article`, (2) I would really like to have a warning-free template, and (3) I would like to load as few packages as possible (thus I'd like to avoid invoking `silence` just for this).

Comment: If you pass `english` to `\documentclass` this is a global option (LaTeX has a list of global options), and global options are by default parsed in packages as well (which is what happened here). You can fix this by removing `english` from the list of global options in your class code. Use `\@expandtwoargs\@removeelement{english}\@classoptionslist\@classoptionslist` if the `english` option was used to achieve this (untested but should do).

Comment: Apart from what Skillmon has said, I don't think `article` itself even reacts to the `english` option. So I think that inheriting to `article` is a non-issue.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for the explanation and for the solution! It works like a charm!
Why don't you post your comment as an answer so that I can mark the question as solved

Comment: If you want to avoid problems with your class settings it might be wiser to choose a name for your class option that does not clash with `babel`'s language identifiers. If you insist on the name `english` it might be an option to handle the class setup with a settings command (like e.g. `siunitx`'s `\sisetup` or `\KOMAoptions` from the KOMA Script classes). The nicest option of course would be to make your class interface with `babel` such that it just uses the language settings selected by the user with `babel`. (Currently the user may have to declare the language in two different places.)

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the valuable point. I however prefer to stick to `english` since I'm writing a multilingual template and I believe `english` is the most "intuitive" option name for the english template.

Comment: I won't try to claim that `english` is not the most intuitive name, but if you really go down the route Skillmon suggested and simply remove `english` from the global option list, you risk confusing your users a lot. It is quite common (and sometimes recommended) to set `babel` language options globally (instead of setting it in `\usepackage{babel}`), a user who just wants `english` will be confused that `babel` doesn't pick up the language.

Comment: @moewe you could show an example on how to better interoperate with `babel` in a class code (if you got the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

LaTeX maintains a list of global options (this is called `\@classoptionslist`) containing the options passed to `\documentclass`. These options are by default forwarded to every package which is loaded after `\documentclass` (this depends on the used interface used in the different packages, the standard LaTeX interface picks up the global options, but packages like `pgfopts`, `l3keys2e` or `expkv-opt` provide mechanisms to only pass the local option list).

You can remove options from the `\@classoptionslist` by using the LaTeX macro `\@removeelement` which takes three arguments, the element which should be removed, the complete list, and the macro in which the filtered list should be stored.

Using this knowledge you could alter your class file to use

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2020/11/07 myclass template]

\newif\ifEnglish\Englishfalse

\DeclareOption{english}
  {%
    \Englishtrue
    \@expandtwoargs\@removeelement{english}\@classoptionslist\@classoptionslist
  }
\DeclareOption*{\ClassWarning{myclass}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
```

which would remove `english` from the list of global options.

---

However, as others have noted (thanks @moewe), it might be a better idea to either cooperate with `babel`, or to use different names. Because of that, the following suggests to use a key=value option with a distinct option name (which is much less likely to clash) for your templates language. I use `expkv-opt` for this, but the same could also be achieved using `pgfkeys` with `pgfopts`, or `l3keys` and `l3keys2e`, or `kvoptions`, or.... (there are a lot of key=value solutions out there).

The following implements `english` and `german` as choices for the `template-language`.

`myclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2020/11/07 myclass template]

\RequirePackage{expkv-opt, expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{myclass}
  {
    choice template-language =
      {
        ,english = \Englishtrue  \Germanfalse
        ,german  = \Englishfalse \Germantrue
      }
  }

\newif\ifEnglish\Englishfalse
\newif\ifGerman\Germanfalse

\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{myclass}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions {myclass}

\LoadClass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
```

Document:

```
\documentclass[template-language=english]{myclass}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\ifEnglish English \fi
\ifGerman Deutscher \fi
Test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent explanation and great solution to @moewe 's point. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the exact nature of your template and the localisation your template provides, but for a certain class of localisation features it would probably be nicest if your template could simply react to the language set by the user via `babel` (and possibly `polyglossia`).

Unfortunately, there are currently two systems for localisation of documents in LaTeX, `babel` and `polyglossia`. The two have slightly different approaches in some areas and no unified interface. There was an effort not too long ago to offer `babel`-equivalent features in `polyglossia` to make it easier for developers to write locale-aware packages, but one still has to write different code for `babel` and `polyglossia`.

For simple translations of strings with `babel` you could do something like the following.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2020/11/07 myclass template]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\rabbit}{\textbf{??? rabbit is missing a translation}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \appto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\rabbit}{rabbit}%
  }%
  \appto\captionsUSenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\rabbit}{rabbit}%
  }%
  \appto\captionsgerman{%
    \renewcommand{\rabbit}{Hase}%
  }%
  \appto\captionsngerman{%
    \renewcommand{\rabbit}{Hase}%
  }%
}

\LoadClass[10pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}
Ohh, \rabbit!
\end{document}
```

You simply define a new macro for your string and then use `\appto` to inject its translation for the language `<language>` into `\captions<language>`. (This is done in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook to make sure that the `\captions<language>` macros exist already and that our changes are not overwritten. Getting the timing right can be a bit of a pain.)

Packages like [`tracklang`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tracklang), [`iflang`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/iflang), [`translator`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/translator) and [`translations`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/translations) can also help you with this.